# Test script is failing when executed via Newman in Jenkins while works fine in postman and no postman console error comes

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, newman

Getting below error when execute tests via Newman - Jenkins. The same request works fine via postman.

```
HTTP request parsing failed with error: "Malformed URI: /v1/addresses?country=AUS&amp;id=AUG|5f246f9b-7c97-4233-8de7-2d57f74cd86b|7.7305OAUGGwvjBwAAAAAIAgEAAAAAB7zTAAAAAAAAADEAAP..ZAAAAAD.....AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMTc3IHBhY2lmaWMgaHd5AAAAAAA-$15"
```

**Newman Report:**

[image]

**Jenkins console output:**
[image]

**Postman Screenshot**
The same test passes in Postman while when executed via newman this fails.
Please note it was working fine till 2 days back but after new deployment this doesn't work anymore. 
[image]

Comment: It's returning a 400 so something is wrong with the request that you're sending. If the tests you have are based on a 200, those are obviously going to fail. What is the actual test and what is the actual response? Those image are a very one sided view of what's going on.

Comment: If you're also using Newman V5, there has been some improvements with the way that URL encoding works in requests. There is an open issues and a workaround for certain things here https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/2312

Comment: It was working fine previously. I compared the URL, Id and everything is same before too. Something changed in development that now its not working in newman but works fine in postman

Comment: Did you try the workaround in the link I provided or even read it?

Comment: Thanks Danny for you help. It worked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in pre-request script and it worked in Newman as well.

```
pm.request.url.query.each((q) => {
     q.update(encodeURI(q.toString()))
});
```